# Adding quantity of products along with add to cart url in magento

Tags: magento-1.8

I have the following add to cart button and input field button in magento.I want to add to cart a product using ajax

```
<input name="qty" type="text" class="input-text qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getMinimalQty($_product)== null?1:$this->getMinimalQty($_product) ?>"/></span>
            <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" link='<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product);?>'><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
```

I want to pass the add to cart url along with quantity of product through ajax. i have tried the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{ 
    $('.btn-cart').click(function()
    {
        var addtocarturl=$(this).attr("link");

        alert(addtocarturl);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: addtocarturl,
            success: function(response) {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Doesnt seem to work...any suggestions?